# WPF RadioButton Databinding with no selection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, radio-button

I've followed the example project at https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720497/Binding-Radio-Buttons-to-a-Single-Property?fid=1853040&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&view=Normal&prof=True&tid=5018079 and I can successfully databind multiple radio buttons so a single backend value for the group. So far I've just gone with the Yes / No option onto a bool and the code as is produces this

[image]

I wanted to maintain a default of both not being checked for a brand new data entry form to force the user to make a selection and figured that simply making the vm binding property type bool? but what I end up with is both buttons selected and the colour gone grey looking like they're disabled, although I can click one and make a selection.

[image]

Any idea how to get them to load as unselected as when I don't databind?

Here's the guts of what's making this work

```
public class RadioButtonCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null && value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}


<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FindCriteria" ObjectType="{x:Type src:TestOptions}" />
    <src:RadioButtonCheckedConverter x:Key="RadioButtonCheckedConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
.
.
.
<RadioButton GroupName="BooleanGroup" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5" 
                IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty, Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonCheckedConverter}, 
                ConverterParameter={x:Static src:MainWindow.BooleanTrue}}">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="True" />
</RadioButton>

<RadioButton GroupName="BooleanGroup" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5" 
                IsChecked="{Binding BooleanProperty, Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonCheckedConverter}, 
                ConverterParameter={x:Static src:MainWindow.BooleanFalse}}">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="False"/>
</RadioButton>


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.options = new TestOptions();
    //this.options.BooleanProperty = true;
    this.DataContext = this.options;
}  

public class TestOptions
{
    public bool? BooleanProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahah!! Got tinkering and found that setting the bound calls from all buttons in the group to false when they're null in the value converter seems

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var ret = value?.Equals(parameter) ?? false;
    return ret;
}
```

Now on load:

[image]

and selecting options:

[image]

[image]